# Enter details in field on one page and pass the same field with the entered details onto another page

Tags: php, wordpress, textfield

I have two fields to enter Registration and Mileage. After entering details and clicking submit I need it to go to a new page with the two fields from the first page but this time the fields are populated with the details entered on the first page.

```
<form action="/results" method="post" id="ukvd_search_form">&nbsp;

<input class="customClassReg" name="UKVD_Vehicle_Registration" 
placeholder="Registration" type="text" /> <input 
class="customClassMileage" name="UKVD_Vehicle_Mileage" 
placeholder="Enter mileage" type="text" />

</form>
```

Comment: `$_POST['UKVD_Vehicle_Registration']` and `$_POST['UKVD_Vehicle_Mileage']`

Comment: Google `php form processing` for a 272 million tutorials